# Ubuntu 19.10 - cannot run .desktop files

Tags: gnome

I have recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my laptop.  I installed Google Chrome because I use a few Chrome apps that I want to run in Ubuntu.  I created shortcuts on the desktop but they just appear as `.desktop` files, and when I double-click them the files just open in text editor.  I have tried making sure the files are set to executable but it still isn't working.  How do I set it so I can run these shortcuts?

As an example of what one of these files contains, here's the contents of the "Word Online" desktop file, which is actually called `chrome-fiombgjlkfpdpkbhfioofeeinbehmajg-Default.desktop`

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Word Online
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=fiombgjlkfpdpkbhfioofeeinbehmajg
Icon=chrome-fiombgjlkfpdpkbhfioofeeinbehmajg-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_fiombgjlkfpdpkbhfioofeeinbehmajg
```

Contents of this file are exactly the same as the equivalent .desktop file on my Desktop PC.  This file works, but I have an earlier version of ubuntu on my Desktop (18.04 LTS) so I'm guessing it's an issue with 19.10....

Comment: What are the contents of said `.desktop` files?

Comment: I've had the same problem with Chromium. I can't try Chrome as it's impossible to set up (does anybody know a good guide?). I tried out Fossa till I had to go back to 19.10 and it had a feature for Chrome that actually ran the shortcuts like programs...but only with Chrome. Hopefully they keep it in the final release. I actually asked about it but with no luck: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208900/installed-chromium-apps-dont-install-or-run-properly?noredirect=1#comment2029557_1208900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I have switched back to 18.04.  Hopefully by the next LTS release this is something that will have been worked out.

Comment: For me it's also not working. Tried everything and it seems when I create my own .desktop is not recognizing well. But I did the `chmod 644 file_name.desktop` and now it shows up... as @Ghazi mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

I believe all you have to do is right click on the `.desktop` file on the Desktop, and click `Allow Launching`.

[image]

which will show the application's icon and make it launchable.

[image]

Comment: I don't see an "Allow Launching" option....

Comment: @SamuelH you can see this option IF the .desktop file is on the Desktop (ie, copied in the desktop folder)

Comment: @cmak.fr - the files ARE copied into the desktop folder.

Comment: For some reason I have to right-click and then click "Allow Launching" every time I log in. Is anyone else having this problem? I'm on 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

`Allow Launching` option doesn't show if file already has execution permission set before you upgraded to new version. To resolve:

```
chmod 644 file_name.desktop
```

then right click on the file in the desktop, you will see allow launching.

Comment: But I hadn't upgraded.  It was a clean install of 19.10.

Comment: Have you tried above solution even though?

Comment: I tried and it worked. I also had my `Exec=` path not right, and when I fixed it, the "Allow launching" appeared.

Answer (score 2):

To get the *Allow Launching* option in the contextual menu you need to change the permissions  to **-rwxr-xr-x**

you can do:

```
chmod 755 <you file>.desktop
```

Comment: this works. but ubuntu makes .desktop experience awful

Comment: @Jake did you try a KDE desktop based distribution (Kubuntu, openSUSE...) ? These could be a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

since 19.10 there were some changes in GNOME.

from now on you have to put your .desktop files in spacial locations to execute them.

if you have a local installation or a script that should be executed place the .desktop file in:

```
~/.local/share/applications$
```

if the app should be executable for every user you have to use the root dir.

```
/usr/share/applications
```

to copy things the you have to be root or use sudo. for example:

```
sudo cp MyApp.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

next thing is important as well. If one of the paths in the .desktop file is wrong your app will not appear in the app browser.

it is remanded to use "" for the path. because if the is a space or a spacial symbol in the path this could cause problems. **You can NOT use ~/ in desktop files!** So always use the whole path to your icon and executable.

Example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyApp
Comment=open source CAD program
Exec="/home/USER/path to your app/MyApp.AppImage"
Icon=/home/USER/path_to_your_icons/ICON.png
Terminal=False
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Does not work, Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with this in 19.10, but I wasn't willing to downgrade since I installed to ZFS rpool (highly recommended).

I tried to create .desktop files for web links manually, and also could not see the "allow launching" option when right-clicking on them.  This might be different for application launchers, but for manually created web links, it does not appear.

So here's how I figured out how to do it:

- In Chrome, open up the web page
- Go to the 3-dots menu in the top right and select "more tools -->
  Create Shortcut"
- Name the shortcut (displayed in Window/Tab) and select whether you want the shortcut to open a new
  window or in another tab in Chrome (default)
- Link name defaults a unique identifier, not the name you just gave the shortcut - but don't worry about that
- Lastly, HERE's where you right-click on the desktop shortcut and select "Allow Launching", and in my case it renamed the shortcut with the name I had just given it and also changes to the Chrome icon

It's actually really easy once you know what to do, and appears to work flawlessly.

Note - the actual files themselves still reflect the UUID given to them by chrome during the creation process.  Example:

[image: Desktop in terminal revealing UUIDs for Chrome-created shortcuts]

Here's what an example .desktop file (this web page) created using this process has in it:

[image: Chrome-created desktop shortcut opened in vim]

Note - DO NOT rename the UUID string to something else, I tried it and the shortcut appears not to work anymore.

If you want to "uninstall" the shortcut you can just delete it, or in the open shortcut there's an option in the 3-dot menu to "Uninstall "

Reference: https://support.patientrewardshub.com/hc/en-us/articles/200086137-Creating-a-Website-Shortcut-on-your-Desktop

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather strange solution, but still it helped me: I also did not have the "Allow Launching" option, and I tried to recreate the Desktop folder. I copied it through the terminal, deleted the original of this folder and then renamed the copy back to Desktop (maybe instead you can just rename the Desktop folder and then return its name back). After that, I rebooted the computer and the option "Allow Launching" appeared. I have no idea why this worked, but it worked -_-