# Installed Chromium apps don't install or run properly

Tags: launcher, chromium

I installed Chromium browser after having some problems with getting Chrome (which I removed) to update. I now have Chromium Version 80.0.3987.87 installed and have a number of Apps in the Chromium Apps.
When I clicked a greyed app in the Apps and told it to install, it puts the 'text file' launcher on the desktop but when I go to run it by clicking the 'text file' it does not launch but opens like a text file.

I don't know what is wrong with it.
What do I do?

Comment: Are you installing it on Ubuntu, which version? How did you install it?

Comment: What's the name of the text file and what's in it? What program opens it when you click it?

Comment: Yes, I have Ubuntu 18.04. I installed Chromium from the Ubuntu Software Center. The Apps are the web apps that you can make in Chromium/Chrome. When I install one of those I get the text file on my desktop and when I was using Chrome all I had to do was click the desktop one for the app and it would ask me if I wanted to install and launch it but now, with Chromium it just opens it as a text file in the text editor.